# How to stop some javascript file from loading?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Some third party javascript is included in my HTML page.
It adds some sharing buttons to my webpage, and is called as like

```
<script src=http://something/something.js></script>
```

But sometimes I would like not to load this javascript at all. It could be solved on the server side, which would block, under some conditions, the above mentioned line from appearing at the webpage. But this is not possible to remove this tag from the HTML at all due to technical reasons, neither by server side (like PHP) nor by javascript (eg. by using document.write to put the tag there only when needed). I need to resolve this in javascript only, and I need to BLOCK the script tag if condition is met, meaning the tag always exists in the HTML.

Is there any possibility to block the something.js URL mentioned above from loading? So I would, for example, execute some other javascript before or after it. I thought that it would be possible this way, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
<script>
   (function(){
      var scripts=document.getElementsByTagName('script');
      for (var i=0; i<scripts.length; i++) 
         if (scripts[i].src && scripts[i].src=='http://something...')
            scripts[i].parentNode.removeChild(scripts[i]);
   })();
</script>

<script src=http://something/something.js></script>
```

This doesn't work because when the script is called, it cannot see another `<script>` tag below at that moment. If I put the script below, it detects the script with src attribute, but it is too late to remove the element since it has already executed (and pasted sharing button elements to the webpage).

Is there any other way to stop loading of the third party script? Thank you

EDIT: updated the fact that the third party javascript needs to be in the HTML every time due to some internal reasons (despite the fact I disagree with that, I can do nothing about it).

Comment: Have a look at this Javascript lazy loading example here: http://friendlybit.com/js/lazy-loading-asyncronous-javascript/

Comment: @Jamie: The unquoted attribute syntax is [entirely valid](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#attributes-0) when used correctly, as it is above.

Answer (score 4):

a simple solution could be:

```
<script>
if(yourcondition){
    document.write('<script src=\"http://something/something.js\" type=\"text/javascript\"><\/script>');
}
else{
    document.write('<script src=\"http://something/OTHER.js\" type=\"text/javascript\"><\/script>');
}
</script>
```

`yourcondition` can be a boolean stored in a cookie or localstorage. Or you can set it to `true` or `false` depending your needs.
Also note that the source value in your script tag must be encapsulated between `"`

Comment: I forgot to mention that the HTML tag with the third party javascript needs to be written to the page, I cannot do it by not printing the tag. I need to stop loading of the existing tag.

Comment: may I ask why? and where in the load process it need to stop loading?

Comment: It is actually a bit complicated to explain why, you have to trust me :)

Comment: can you try explaining? I'm curious ;-)

Comment: @TomasMatejicek Why dont you just check if the script tag exists on each page you are using and if not then just return? Going by the code provided the Javascript simply takes the link from the script and adds the buttons. If you check whether the link exists then surely thats your condition to build the buttons?

Comment: honestly I don't see any reasons why a script tag should be present if it 's code is not used.  So I'm really curious.

Comment: The fact is that my real problem is different than the one I described. I modified it to provide easily understandable example. But the core is still the same - I'm searching for a way how to use javascript to block some other javascript :)

Answer (score 2):

If the script relies on being in the document during the initial parsing because it outputs HTML where it appears (e.g., via `document.write`), as it seems to from your `hidemeifnecessary` example, then your "hide me" approach is probably the best you can do client-side.

If the script *didn't* need to be in the page during the main parsing, you could lazy-load it, but from your question that doesn't seem to be the case.

As you said in the question, the right answer here really is to deal with this server-side.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the HTML tag with the third party javascript needs to be written to the page, I cannot do it by not printing the tag. I need to stop loading of the existing tag.

Comment: Hey T.J. good answer. I would also suggest that if the OP takes the hide element approach that they use classes rather than single select ID's to capture the event on multiple pages.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure your script is loaded as soon as possible. I load mine right after the opening head tag. In that script select all tags you want to block (in my case script, iframe and img) and iterate through them. Add the event listener "beforescriptexecute" to them and trigger preventDefault like this:

```
                bsePd = element.addEventListener('beforescriptexecute', e => {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    e.target.removeEventListener('beforescriptexecute', bsePd);
                    console.log('Prevented script from execution:', e.target.src);
                });
```

With that you catch already existing scripts. For those added dynamically you can add the event Listener DOMNodeInserted and wait for them to come.

Thats how I made a cookie consent manager I needed for a site where it was not possible to do it whit PHP because of heavy caching mechanisms.

Comment: Not a standard listener for executing it as per MDN. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/beforescriptexecute_event